# The isomorphism between a projective line with a specified point removed and the affine line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Say you're given a point with coordinates $p=(x:y) \in \mathbb{P}^1$ and you'd like to write down the isomorphism $\mathbb{P}^1-p \cong \mathbb{A}^1$. How would one define the map and it's inverse? Thanks!

Comment: Compose $\mathbb P^1 - p \cong \mathbb P^1 - [1:0] \cong \mathbb A^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make @MooS answer explicit: suppose that the point $p$ has coordinates $[a: b]$ (so that I can use $x$ and $y$ as variables).

Step 1: move $[a: b]$ to the point at infinity, $[1: 0]$: 
$$
[x: y] \mapsto [ax+by : bx - ay]
$$

Step 2: Map the punctured projective line (punctured at infinity) to the affine line: 
$$
[x: y] \mapsto \frac{x}{y}
$$

(This is well-defined because the point at infinity, where $y = 0$, is missing).

The composition is

$$
[x: y] \mapsto \frac{ax+by}{bx-ay}
$$
which does the job.

Comment: Dear John, your maps are not well defined. For example in your last map, assuming $a\neq b$, what is the image of $[1:1]=[2:2]\in \mathbb P^1\setminus \{[a:b]\}$ in $\mathbb A^1$ ? Is it  $\frac {1}{b-a}$ or  $\frac {1}{2b-2a}$ ?

Comment: Thanks, @GeorgesElencwajg; I should never write an answer before the first cup of tea in the morning. I think that tossing in an extra $x$, as I've done, fixes that. At least now the first map is a fractional linear transform. Of course, I could still be wrong -- maybe I need two cups!

Comment: Dear John, maybe another sip? If $a=0, b=1$ your first map would be constant, sending $\mathbb P^1$ to $[1:1]$. Sorry for nitpicking and cheers:-)

Comment: Fixed, I think. (esp since $det  \pmatrix{a & b \\ b & -a} = -(a^2+b^2) \ne 0$, as long as $a$ and $b$ are not both zero.) I may have to move up to coffee!

Comment: BTW, thanks for your gentle corrections -- much appreciated.

Comment: Dear John, your answer is now perfect (+1 of course). Projective geometry is nice but getting to know a fine colleague with a splendid sense of humour is even more satisfying.